# Dynamic Topic Model: Topic Mixture

Tags: spyder, gensim, topic-modeling

Is there any way I can see the distribution over topics (topic mixtures) per document for the Dynamic Topic Model in Spyder using the Gensim module?

I am only aware of 'print_topic_times' that shows one topic (distribution over words) over all time slices.
However, is there any code that allows to see the topix mixture of one document for each time slice?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about Spyder but for visualization of topics it is easiest to use [pyLDAvis](https://github.com/bmabey/pyLDAvis).